# Apply Event Listener to multiple dom elements

Tags: javascript

I created a JavaScript code to auto format some date inputs. The problem is that my code works only on the first input but not the others. 
How can I make my code applied on all the date inputs in my form ?

Is there a way to make the event listener activated on all the inputs ?

I thought about adding different ID to every input and duplicate code, but this will make my code not readable.

Any hints, i tried to iterate over the input using the for loop but it doesn't work either.

```js
var dates = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
date = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i]
function checkValue(str, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};

date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
  });
  this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
});

date.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v, i) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  var output = '';
  
  if (values.length == 3) {
    var year = values[2].length !== 4 ? parseInt(values[2]) + 2000 : parseInt(values[2]);
    var month = parseInt(values[0]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(values[1]);
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (!isNaN(d)) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
      var dates = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()];
      output = dates.map(function(v) {
        v = v.toString();
        return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
      }).join(' / ');
    };
  };
  this.value = output;
});
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
form small {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    align-self: ;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <label for="amount">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="date1" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="date2" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 3</label>
  <input type="text" id="date3" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  
</form>
```

**Edit:** 
I corrected the inputs Id so that they become unique.

**Edit 2 :**
In my solution, i'm parsing the input and I add spaces before and after every slash. I want to eliminate those spaces. To do so, I modified this line :

```
this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
```

I replaced 14 by 10. But this modification made deleting the data impossible.
For example : 06/07/ can't be deleted.

Comment: All dom element must have unique id

Comment: This is not the problem. But yeah you're right, the answer covers this remark as well.

Comment: Please check the code snippet works before asking questions other than why it doesn't. The answer  to the "is there a way..." part is "yes, it's called [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/5217142)"

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I corrected the code (var date instead of dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Iterate over each input directly with `querySelectorAll('input').forEach`. Also note that your HTML is invalid: there should never be more than one element with a particular ID in a document. You left out some of your HTML, which is why the snippet below results in an error at the end:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((date) => {

  function checkValue(str, max) {
    if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
      var num = parseInt(str);
      if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
      str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
    };
    return str;
  };

  date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
    var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
      return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
    if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
    var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
      return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
    });
    this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
  });

  date.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    this.type = 'text';
    var input = this.value;
    var values = input.split('/').map(function(v, i) {
      return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
    });
    var output = '';

    if (values.length == 3) {
      var year = values[2].length !== 4 ? parseInt(values[2]) + 2000 : parseInt(values[2]);
      var month = parseInt(values[0]) - 1;
      var day = parseInt(values[1]);
      var d = new Date(year, month, day);
      if (!isNaN(d)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
        var dates = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()];
        output = dates.map(function(v) {
          v = v.toString();
          return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
        }).join(' / ');
      };
    };
    this.value = output;
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

form input {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 3;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

form input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

form input.error {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}

form label.error {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em
}

form small {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  align-self: ;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <label for="amount">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 3</label>
  <input type="text" id="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>

</form>
```

Comment: Very quick answer. Thank you !

Comment: What should I modify to avoid adding spaces before and after slashes ?
I changed this line :
this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
to : 
this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 10);
But then I can't delete the date to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can process events on multiple nodes in the same manner by listening for the events on a common parent node and only processing those fired on particular targets. The method is called "event delegation", discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) for example, with additional discussion and related questions easily found.

To apply the method in this case, I declared the date handler functions as named functions (they could have been written inline), added a `data-type="date"` attribute value to each of the date inputs to identify them (other ways could be found), and checked events when they reached the form element:

```js
function checkValue(str, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};
  
function dateInput(date) {  // date is input object argument
  var input = date.value;
  if (/\D\/$/.test(input))
    input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  if (values[0]) {
    values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  }
  if (values[1]) {
    values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  }
  var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
  });
  date.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
}

function dateBlur(date) {  // date is input object argument
  var input = date.value;
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v, i) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  var output = '';
  if (values.length == 3) {
    var year = values[2].length !== 4 ? parseInt(values[2]) + 2000 : parseInt(values[2]);
    var month = parseInt(values[0]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(values[1]);
    var d = new Date(year, month, day);
    if (!isNaN(d)) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = d.toString();
      var dates = [d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()];
      output = dates.map(function(v) {
        v = v.toString();
        return v.length == 1 ? '0' + v : v;
      }).join(' / ');
    }
  }
  date.value = output;
}
// delegate event handling from the form element

var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  if(e.target.dataset.type == "date") {
    dateBlur(e.target);
  }
},false);
form.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if(e.target.dataset.type == "date") {
    dateInput(e.target);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
form small {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    align-self: ;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <label for="amount">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="date1" data-type="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 2</label>
  <input type="text" id="date2" data-type="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  </br>
  <label for="amount">Date 3</label>
  <input type="text" id="date3" data-type="date" />
  <small>Enter date as Month / Day / Year</small>
  
</form>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you for your solution. It allows easy targeting of data fields.